# ReadableStream from a network resource URL

Tags: node.js

All the materials I've found about ReadableStream(s) are related to file system operations. I'm working with a library that only supports a ReadableStream as an input for data, and I would like to supply a ReadableStream to a remote network resource. Ideally, this would effectively stream data from that URL to the API interface.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the http package has request which returns a Readable Stream as the first parameter in the 'response' event.

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request(file);
req.end();
req.on('response', function(readable_stream) {

});
```